# Setting theme to a Button with custom drawable

Tags: java, android, button, drawable, highlight

I have an application, in which I am using custom drawables as a button background.
However, I didn't create seperate drawables for focused, selected etc. status.

My question is, if without defining that additional Drawables, is it possible to highlight the button with default Android.Holo Color (Blue)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors (state list), which then gets assigned to the view in the layout, that modify how the view should behave during different events.

So the selector (lets call it myselector) might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" enconding "utf-8">
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     //When the view gets pressed the drawable gets set. 
     //You could also use android:color
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="<Your drawable>"

     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="<Another drawable>">

 </selector>
```

Then you set the selector for your button inside the layout (or in code if you want):

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/mybutton"
  android:text="Click me!"
  android:background="@drawable/myselector" //Here the selector is set
/>
```

And that should be it. You can read up on selectors/state lists [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that is not an answer to my question. I would like to know if it is possible to achieve with only one drawable

Comment: You want your button to be highlighted with a color when pressed, no?

Comment: Yes, but I want to use my custom Drawable as a background (and I don't want to create another drawable for focused state, also because I don't know exact color and transparency values for Holo theme)

Comment: You don't need to create another drawable for the focused state. You just put android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" in the item that matches the state you want. And your other 'custom' drawable, you set that in the state where that matches.

Comment: So this will just make blue transparent rectangle overlay my Drawable right?